# Weird error from the Eclipse GWT plugin when having a separate source folder for resources

Tags: eclipse, gwt, cssresource

I have an Eclipse GWT project with two source folders: One for source code and one for resources. This should and does work fine, but nevertheless Eclipse shows the following error message:

> Resource file style.css is missing (expected at com.example.gwt.client)

If have the a class `Resources` in my source code source folder:

```
package com.example.gwt.client;

import com.google.gwt.resources.client.*;

interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
    @Source("style.css")
    Style style();
}
```

The references CSS file is in the same package in the source folder I use for resources.

It's not really a problem, since it definitely works, but I would like to get rid of the error message in any case, it's making me nervous. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this GWT issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4600&q=resource%20file%20is%20missing&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars). Configure the resources folder as a source folder in Eclipse and the errors in the editor will go away.

Comment: Maven automatically added it as a source folder, that didn't help. However, removing, adding it again and then updating Maven project information did the trick.

Comment: Also be sure that exclusion patterns is empty for resources path